# What is the minimum order of a faithful representation of a finite cyclic group?

Tags: representation-theory

What is the minimum order of a faithful representation of a finite cyclic group $C_N$?

More pressingly, what is the minimum order of a faithful representation of the product of two finite cyclic groups $C_N\times C_M$?
In particular, what is the order of the irreducible faithful representation of $(C_3)^2$?

Comment: By *order* do you mean *dimension*?

Comment: Also, in which category are these representations? Vector spaces over which field?

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes. By order, I mean the dimension of the matrix. Representations over GL(n,R)

Comment: Apologies for not making myself clear, I am only interested in real valued matrices. 
Thank you for clarifying the terminology.
I am also having trouble applying the same line of reasoning to real representations. Are you saying that if their product is non-cyclic then the degree of the minimal representation of their product is the sum of the degrees of the minimal representations of the cyclic groups? I think I'm misunderstanding something, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

For a finite cyclic group $C_N$, there is an obvious faithful representation into the complex numbers, where a generator is represented as a primitive $N$th root of unity.
$$ \rho : C_N \to \mathbb{C}^\times, \quad \rho(k) = \exp\left(\frac{2 \pi i k}{N} \right).$$
If you want a real-valued representation instead, you need to go up one dimension, and instead represent a generator as a rotation through a $1/N$th turn on the plane:
$$ \psi : C_N \to \mathbb{R}^2, \quad \psi(k) = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(2 \pi k / N) & -\sin(2 \pi k / N) \\
\sin(2 \pi k / N) & \cos(2 \pi k / N)
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $\psi$ is exactly what happens if you just treat $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Are these representations as small as possible? The complex representations are as small as possible since they have dimension 1. In the real case, provided that $N \geq 3$, the representation $\psi$ is as small as a faithful representation can get. (Why? The group of units $\mathbb{R}^\times = \{\pm 1\}$, and so a group of order 3 or more cannot embed inside a one-dimensional representation).

---

How about direct products of cyclic groups? Here things get a bit more tricky, since sometimes direct products of cyclic groups are themselves cyclic, i.e. $C_N \times C_M \cong C_{NM}$ if $N, M$ are coprime. However, after taking this into account, I think that the following construction, which puts together the representations in the previous section, should provide you with the small faithful representations that you need.

If $\rho_V : G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ and $\rho_W : H \to \operatorname{GL}(W)$ are both representations of groups, then you can define a representation on $V \oplus W$ by "block-diagonal" matrices, i.e.
$$\rho_{V \oplus W}(g, h)(v + w) = \rho_V(g)(v) + \rho_W(h)(w).$$
By construction, this new representation has kernel
$$ \ker \rho_{V \oplus W} = \ker \rho_V \times \ker \rho_W \subseteq G \times H.$$
Therefore, if $\rho_V$ and $\rho_W$ are faithful representations of $G$ and $H$, then $\rho_{V \oplus W}$ is a faithful representation of $G \times H$.